# Event type can't be Action<>?

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates

this works

```
public event Func<int,int> createEvents;
```

but why not this ?

```
public event Action<int> createEvents;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public event Action<int> CreateEvents;`

Is completely valid. Maybe your Event Handling method does not match with the `Action<T>` delegate.

Maybe you have something like this:

```
    public event Action<int> CreateEvents;
    public event Func<int, int> CreateEvents2;

    public int OnCreateEvents2(int value)
    {
        Func<int, int> handler = CreateEvents2;
        if (handler != null) return handler(value);

        return 0;
    }

    public void OnCreateEvents(int value)
    {
        Action<int> handler = CreateEvents;
        if (handler != null) handler(value);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, now i tried and it worked but i don't know what i have done wrong before